# Having trouble understanding the format of execvp() arguments

Tags: c, exec

I'm currently working on a project where I need to use execvp.
I'm having troubles using this because I can't get it to work so maybe it's got something to do with the way I'm passing arguments.
I need to execute a program provided to us by our professors.
The arguments to execute this program are:
`$ ./bin/aurrasd-filters/aurrasd-gain-double < samples/sample-1-so.m4a > output.m4a`
This is how I was trying to set the arguments to make this work:

```c
int main () {
    char *agr2[] = {"./bin/aurrasd-filters/aurrasd-gain-double", "<", "samples/sample-1-so.m4a", ">", "output.m4a", NULL};
    if (!fork()) {
        execvp(*agr2, agr2);
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Terminated"\n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Would this put all the arguments in the correct place? I can't seem to figure out where the error is.

Comment: I think your problem is that `execvp` does not implement I/O redirection, so the `<` and `>` and their arguments are being passed directly to the program as part of _its_ arguments, which is not what it expects. Change `./bin/aurrasd-filters/aurrasd-gain-double` to `/bin/echo` to see this for yourself. This is not an answer because the _fix_ depends on more details of what you're being asked to do for your assignment; I can't help you any more without a full transcript of the instructions you were given.

Comment: Hi, would it work if I used execv() instead? From what I understand it would allow me to do this right?

Comment: No, none of the functions whose name starts with `exec` implement I/O redirection.  `system` _does_ (sort of) but it takes a single argument string, not an argument vector, and it does the forking itself, so it's quite likely that you're not supposed to use it.  I'm actually betting that the goal of the assignment is to teach you to implement I/O redirection by hand, which is too big of a question for this site. Again, I need to see a full transcript of the instructions you were given to help any more.

Comment: If you want to handle the input/output redirection yourself, you'll need to use `pipe` in conjunction with one of the `dup` system calls so that stdin and stdout refer to the desired files.  I.e. you'll need to do the same thing that a shell does.

Comment: @zwol Thank you so much, I didn't know anything about I/O redirection.. after spending some time reading up I've finally managed to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was redirect stdout and stdin. `<` and `>` weren't arguments for the executable as I thought.
It would look something like this:

```c
int main () {
    char *arg[] = {"./bin/aurrasd-filters/aurrasd-gain-double", NULL};
    char *input = "samples/sample-1-so.m4a";
    char *output = "output.m4a";
    if (!fork()) {
        int input_f;
        if ((input_f = open(input, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
            perror("Error opening input file");
            return -1;
        }
        dup2(input_f, 0);
        close(input_f);
       
        int output_f;
        if ((output = open(output, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
            perror("Error creating output file");
            return -1;
        }
        dup2(output_f, 1);
        close(output_f);
        execvp(*arg, arg);
        _exit(0);
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As @zwol mentioned above, we need to handle the I/O redirection, I'm doing this using the `dup2()` function, setting the input file as stdin and creating an output file and setting it as stdout.
This worked for me, maybe it will help someone in the future..